# Explain why $|x - y|^2 $ is not a metric.

Tags: metric-spaces

Define $d(x,y)  = |x - y|^2$ . Explain why d is not a metric.

I have seen that the first two properties of a metric hold, so naturally it's left to prove that the triangle inequality does not hold. But after some algebra, I get stuck at the following:

$2|y|(|x| + |z|)-2|x||z|- 2|y|^2<= 0 $

Am I missing something obvious here? I am not sure how to prove that this inequality doesn't hold from here.

Comment: On what space.?

Comment: Its R x R. Sorry I couldn't figure out how to format that part on this site @MyGlasses

Comment: Give an counterexample.

Comment: For what it's worth, on $\Bbb{R}$, we have $d(0,4)=16$ and $d(0,2)=d(2,4)=4$, so we don't have $d(0,4)\le d(0,2)+d(2,4)$.  Probably works on $\Bbb{R}^2$ too:  just look at $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$, and $(0,4)\in \Bbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

On $\mathbb{R}$ we have: $$d(0,1)=1 $$ and $$d(0,\frac{1}{2})=d(\frac{1}{2},1)=\frac{1}{4}$$ under your proposed metric. Hence $$d(0,1)>d(0,\frac{1}{2}) +d(\frac{1}{2},1). $$

Note that this extends to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by simply taking the second coordinate zero.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this?

Comment: Or I suppose providing a counterexample is proof enough

Comment: Well, the same argument works for any normed vector space.

Comment: Excellent. thank you