# Checking whether $X=\mathbb R$ with $d(x,y)=\min\{ \sqrt{|x-y|},|x-y|^2\}$ is a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Examine whether $d$ is a metric on $X=\mathbb{R}$ where $d\left(x,y\right)=\min\{ \sqrt{|x-y|},|x-y|^2\}$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

I think it is not.
Even though it satisfies all other properties but it doesn't satisfy triangle inequality.

Take $x=2,y=1.5,z=1$
$d\left(x,z\right)=1$

$d\left(x,y\right)=0.25$

$d\left(y,z\right)=0.25$

Can someone confirm and verify.
It is correct or not.

Comment: Looks correct. Well done.

Comment: @Cornman Thank you Sir

Comment: This can also be helpful: [Explain why $|x - y|^2 $ is not a metric.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2154134) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24d(x%2Cy)%3D%7Cx-y%7C%5E2%24&p=1).

Comment: If $0\leq u\leq 1$ then $u^2\leq \sqrt u.$ So if $x,y,z\in [0,1]$ then $d(x,y)+d(y,x)\geq d(x,z)\iff$ $ \iff (x-y)^2+(y-z)^2\geq (x-z)^2 \iff$ $ (y-\frac {x+z}{2})^2\geq (\frac {x-z}{2})^2 \iff$ $ |y-\frac {x+z}{2}|\geq |\frac {x-z}{2}|.$.. So the Triangle Inequality fails when $0\leq x<y<z\leq 1.$

Comment: You are right...